# css list collision

Tags: html, css

li and ul are already defined throughout the website and i have a gallery page that i use a nextgen gallery plugin.

However there is a collision with the li style and nextgen li style i guess,

web page global css li is overriding the gallery's li and putting check box next to it, in which other pages are done like this.

How can i reset this only for this block of gallery? possibly place in a div?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `!important` isn't working then it sounds like you need to work out the most specific rule that is giving it the unwanted style.

Use Firebug in Firefox. You can see the most specific rules, disable them, and edit them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) of your selector and change it accordingly.

Alternatively, open the gallery's CSS and add `!important`.

Comment: I'm of the view that `!important` is to be used only for testing.

Comment: @Robusto Fair enough. I use it as a last resort myself.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the second stylesheet after the global stylesheet, that way the second one will override the first